# How can I pull video profile data from Adobe Dynamic Media?

Tags: java, dynamic, aem, media

I need to get video profile renditions into my sling model (basically resolutions for different types such as 540x360 etc). For that I have a path for the video profile in crx (/conf/global/settings/dam/dm/presets/video/testvideoprofile). The result I am expecting is a list of those renditions defined in video profile. I am using the below code in my sling model:

```
    @Inject
@ResourcePath(path = "/conf/global/settings/dam/dm/presets/video/testvideoprofile")
Resource videoObjects;

@PostConstruct
public Resource getVideoObjects(){
    System.out.println( videoObjects + " = Resource Path");
    return videoObjects;
}
```

Is this the correct approach? Does DM allow its reource path to be converted into resource object in this way?